# Google Maps | Code only runs localhost

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, localhost

I want to use Google Maps API v3 for a website I'm making...
I've made and tried the code on localhost and it runs, then I've uploaded the files to my ftp and I signed up for an API KEY. All right. I've modified the google maps's src file, adding the key but it don't runs. I dont know to make it runs.

I use AJAX.

http://www.superclub95.com/#vive-superclub/localizacion

Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

You have dozens of Network-Errors, and script-errors too, did you ever take a look inside the console?

However, nothing happens because you're not calling `initialize()`.